# Linq to EF in lightswitch WCF RIA Services

Tags: linq, wcf, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have been trying for days now to solve the following problem in WCF RIA for lightswitch using linq:

the entity is:

moveDate  Direction moveQuantity moveSignedQty

moveSignedQty is positive for In and negative for Out Direction

What I need to do is create a WCF Service in the form

tDate OBalance CBalance

CBalance is the sum of moveSignedQty for a particular moveDate
OBalance is the sum of mpveSignedQt for the previous moveDate; it is zero if there in no previous day value.

My approach below did not work:

```
     Dim close = From c In Me.Context.StockMovements
                        Order By c.DateOfMovement
                        Group New With {c} By _
                        tranDate = CDate(c.DateOfMovement) _
                        Into g = Group
                        Let cBal = g.Sum(Function(s) s.c.SignedQuantity_KG)
                        Let fDate = g.OrderBy(Function(d) d.c.DateOfMovement).FirstOrDefault
                      Select New accStockBalance With {
                          .TransactionDate = tranDate, _
                          .ClosingBalance = cBal}

    Dim sBal = close.GroupBy(Function(d) d.TransactionDate).Select( _
                                                   Function(b)
                                                       Dim subb = b.OrderBy(Function(t) t.TransactionDate)
                                                       Return subb.Select( _
                                                           Function(s, i) New With {
                                                               .TransactionDate = s.TransactionDate, _
                                                               .ClosingBalance = subb.ElementAt(i).ClosingBalance, _
                                                               .OpeningBalance = If(i = 0, 0, subb.ElementAt(i - 1).ClosingBalance)})
                                                   End Function)
```

Example:

> moveDate    Direction moveQuantity moveSignedQty
>   13/02/2013                                        In        30          30
>   13/02/2013   Out       4            -4
>   13/02/2013   Out       10           -10
>   14/02/2013   Out       4            -4
>   14/02/2013   Out       4            -4
>   14/02/2013   In        7             7
>   15/02/2013   In        15            15

Expected result:

tDate        OBalance  cBalance
13/02/2013   0         16
14/02/2013   16        15
15/02/2013   15        30

The last bit sBal threw up an error that lambda statements cannot be converted to expression trees.

Kindly guide me. I have read several Q and A in this and other forums help please.

Please forgive my terrible formatting couldnt figure out how to format the example to table format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function below is composed of 2 statements.

```
Function(b)
  Dim subb = ...
  Return ...
```

This kind of function can't be used in LINQ query.
Moreover, the operators `ElementAt` and `Select` using index arguments aren't supported by EntityFramework.

I show you here a solution. It is written in C#. I do not think you'll have difficulty translating the code in VB. Furthermore, I do not use the *fluent* LINQ syntax that I do not find very understandable. Finally, for pedagogical concern I avoid using anonymous types.

The first thing to do is actually write a query that sums the movements by date. This request must allow to obtain a list of object (`MovementSumItem` class) each containing the date and the sum of the movements of the day.

```
class MovementSumItem
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int? TotalQty { get; set; }
}
```

The `TotalQty` property is declared as nullable. I'll explain why later.

I do not understand why your `close` query is so complicated!?! You just need to use the `GroupBy` operator once. And there is no interest in using the OrderBy operator.

```
IQueryable<MovementSumItem> movementSumItemsQuery =
  context.StockMovements
      .GroupBy(
          // group key selector: the key is just the date
          m => m.MoveDate,
          // project each group to a MovementSumItem   
          (groupKey, items) => new MovementSumItem {
              // date is the key of the group
              Date = groupKey,
              // items group sum
              TotalQty = items.Sum(i => i.SignedQty),
          });
```

Now, we must be able to determine for each item which is the previous item. And this of course without first execute the query below.

Here is the *logical expression* I propose:

```
Func<MovementSumItem,MovementSumItem> previousItemSelector = item =>
    movementSumItemsQuery           // from all items
    .Where(b => b.Date < item.Date) // consider only those corresponding to a previous date
    .OrderByDescending(b => b.Date) // ordering them from newest to oldest
    .FirstOrDefault();              // take the first (so, the newest) or null if collection is empty
```

This expression does not use any *index* notion. It is therefore compatible with Entity Framework.

Combining this expression with the query above, we can write the complete query. This final request must allow to obtain a list of object (`BalanceItem` class) each containing the date, the opening balance (sum of movements from previous item) and the closing balance (sum of movements from current item).

```
class BalanceItem
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int OpeningBalance { get; set; }
    public int ClosingBalance { get; set; }
}
```

Logically, the final query can be written:

```
IQueryable<BalanceItem> balanceItemsQuery =
    movementSumItemsQuery
    .Select(
        item => new BalanceItem() {
            Date = item.Date,
            OpeningBalance = previousItemSelector(item).TotalQty ?? 0,
            ClosingBalance = item.TotalQty ?? 0
        });
```

**Unfortunately Entity Framework does not support the invocation of the function `previousItemSelector`. So we must integrate the expression in the query.**

```
IQueryable<BalanceItem> balanceItemsQuery =
    movementSumItemsQuery
    .Select(
        item => new BalanceItem()
        {
            Date = item.Date,
            OpeningBalance = movementSumItemsQuery
                .Where(b => b.Date < item.Date)
                .OrderByDescending(b => b.Date)
                .FirstOrDefault().TotalQty ?? 0,
            ClosingBalance = item.TotalQty ?? 0
        });
```

Finally, to run the query, simply use (for example) the `ToList` operator.

```
List<BalanceItem> result = balanceItemsQuery.ToList();
```

Moreover, balanceItemsQuery being IQueryable, you can specify the query by adding, for example, a filter on the date:

```
IQueryable<BalanceItem> balanceItemsOfTheYearQuery = balanceItemsQuery
    .Where(x => x.Date.Year == 2014);
```

Finally, you can verify that the query executes well via a single SQL query using the `ToString` function of the Query object.

```
Console.WriteLine(balanceItemsQuery.ToString());
```

Why TotalQty is declared nullable?

Otherwise, the OpeningBalance value expression should be written:

```
 OpeningBalance = movementSumItemsQuery
     .Where(b => b.Date < item.Date)
     .OrderByDescending(b => b.Date)
     .FirstOrDefault() == null ? 0 : movementSumItemsQuery
         .Where(b => b.Date < item.Date)
         .OrderByDescending(b => b.Date)
         .FirstOrDefault().TotalQty
```

However, the comparison `.FirstOrDefault() == null` is not supported by Entity Framework.

Comment: Wow nlips thanks just saw you answer. I will give it a spin and let you know. Not sure I understand everything you said. I will be back. Thanks once more. Oh, so why is the TotalQty in the first class nullable?

Comment: nlips. Just tried your codes and they ran well without errors. many thanks. I will check the values to see if they are ok.

Comment: @Aklama If a response is interesting, vote! Read [Why is voting important?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)